# Can't password_hash() be easily abused to run a DoS attack due to its long runtime?

Tags: php

Considering an implementation of `password_hash()` where parameters are set so that 1 execution of the function takes 0.1 seconds - doesn't this make the webserver very vulnerable to DoS attacks due to the long runtime?

And if yes, how could one prevent this kind of attack?

Comment: Certainly, all requests can be used for that, regardless of what code is actually executed. Protection from DOS attacks is not done by limiting the functions one can use in an implementation but by analyzing the stream of requests and block certain patterns so that no application code is executed at all for such requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect your website by DOS attacks.

Using method like:

- Using `reCaptcha`
- Http to Https
- Storing Passwords / Verifying logins
- Session data when user login
- Require password with difficult pattner.
- Using services like: `Cloudflare`

[hash_pbkdf2()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) can be used to slow down your hash process to guard against brute-force by creating a bottleneck for an attacker. Don't DDOS your own server though: Use rate-limiting to avoid creating a DDOS vector.

Read more at here:
http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php